# Kernel Panic With Cheap Wi-Fi Usb Adapter

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, kernel, hardware

I've just bought a cheap usb wifi adapter from ebay. It is mediatek based, `lsusb` outputs:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp.
```

I'm on 3.13 kernel, and the driver provided in the cd shipped with the adapter didn't wanted to compile. I've followed [this guide](http://kyoushuu.wordpress.com/2014/04/01/compiling-rt2870-wifi-driver-in-fedora/) and then everything compiled fine.

The problem is, when I plug in the adapter it connects fine but, after a couple of seconds, the kernel panics. Can anyone help me find out what's wrong? Here's a picture of the screen when the PC crashes:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have a device with the same device ID 148f:7601, and I suffered the same problem.
I'm not an expert, but I've found out that [Victor Martinez](https://code.launchpad.net/~victored/+junk/mt7601U-linux-driver-64bit) solved the problem.
(I'm writting this post right after my computer connects to a wifi network!)

You can download the modified driver from [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~victored/+junk/mt7601U-linux-driver-64bit/tarball/2).
After downloading it, follow the below instructions to compile and install:

```
$ cd Downloads
$ tar -xzf \~victored-+junk-mt7601U-linux-driver-64bit-r2.tgz
$ cd \~victored/+junk/mt7601U-linux-driver-64bit/
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
$ sudo modprobe mt7601Usta
```

I've tried it on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit, with version 3.13.0-24-generic kernel (a kernel in the Ubuntu install DVD)
I think 64bit kernel can get the kernel panic problem.